# How can I change Vim's start or intro screen?

Tags: external-command, startup

When I start Vim without any files, I always see this:

```
              VIM - Vi IMproved

               version 7.4.580
           by Bram Moolenaar et al.
 Vim is open source and freely distributable

        Become a registered Vim user!
type  :help register<Enter>   for information

type  :q<Enter>               to exit
type  :help<Enter>  or  <F1>  for on-line help
type  :help version7<Enter>   for version info
```

How can I change this?

Specifically, I'd like to put the output of a shell command (`fortune`) here.

I know about [vim-startify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-startify); but I don't need all those features. I just want to show some simple text...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the code that I extracted from `vim-startify`; the key parts are creating a new buffer on the `VimEnter` autocmd, putting some text in that, and then mapping the `i` to start a new buffer and then go to insert mode.

I put the below in a [little plugin](https://github.com/Carpetsmoker/startscreen.vim) which adds some settings and such, but the basic concept is exactly the same.

```
fun! Start()
    " Don't run if: we have commandline arguments, we don't have an empty
    " buffer, if we've not invoked as vim or gvim, or if we'e start in insert mode
    if argc() || line2byte('$') != -1 || v:progname !~? '^[-gmnq]\=vim\=x\=\%[\.exe]$' || &insertmode
        return
    endif

    " Start a new buffer ...
    enew

    " ... and set some options for it
    setlocal
        \ bufhidden=wipe
        \ buftype=nofile
        \ nobuflisted
        \ nocursorcolumn
        \ nocursorline
        \ nolist
        \ nonumber
        \ noswapfile
        \ norelativenumber

    " Now we can just write to the buffer, whatever you want.
    call append('$', "")
    for line in split(system('fortune -a'), '\n')
        call append('$', '        ' . l:line)
    endfor

    " No modifications to this buffer
    setlocal nomodifiable nomodified

    " When we go to insert mode start a new buffer, and start insert
    nnoremap <buffer><silent> e :enew<CR>
    nnoremap <buffer><silent> i :enew <bar> startinsert<CR>
    nnoremap <buffer><silent> o :enew <bar> startinsert<CR>
endfun

" Run after "doing all the startup stuff"
autocmd VimEnter * call Start()
```

Comment: what it is fortune -a ??

Comment: @regedarek It displays a random joke. See:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_(Unix)

Answer (score 7):

Actually the answer is in startify. In [startify.vim](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-startify/blob/master/plugin/startify.vim) around line 15 we can see

```
 autocmd VimEnter * nested
\ if !argc() && (line2byte('$') == -1) && (v:progname =~? '^[-gmnq]\=vim\=x\=\%[\.exe]$')
\ | if get(g:, 'startify_session_autoload') && filereadable('Session.vim')
\ | source Session.vim
\ | else
\ | call startify#insane_in_the_membrane()
\ | endif
\ | endif
\ | autocmd! startify VimEnter
```

So the relevant thing is the `VimEnter` auto command which is called "[after doing all the startup stuff](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#VimEnter)".
The following `if` checks whether this is an empty session (by checking for arguments like `filename`). Basically you can put your code in the place of the second `if`, which is the startify-specific code.

Comment: ... I'd like to know who thought of the function name `insane_in_the_membrane`, and how that has remotely anything to do with its actual code. Because that person is brilliant and this is the best function name I've seen today! :P

Comment: @Doorknob Function was [renamed from "start" to "insane in the membrane"](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-startify/commit/c91cfb29aef9539987fbc438640633ba534d24a9) by Marco Hinz. Given [the original lyrics by Cypress Hill](http://www.lyricsmode.com/lyrics/c/cypress_hill/insane_in_the_brain.html) I'd guess he was worried about how big the method was getting. Or maybe was just listening to it at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's a bit of a hack, but the following one-liner anywhere in the .vimrc file will effectively truncate the Vim splash screen to a length of zero:

```
    set shortmess+=I
```

Comment: "Perhaps it's a bit of a hack" - I don't think so. According to `:help shortmess` this suppresses the `:intro` message and that's what it does.