# How to force quit if input was stdin?

Tags: key-bindings, save

I have

1. <kbd>q</kbd> [mapped to <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>](https://github.com/jalanb/dotjab/blob/master/vim/vimrc#L91)
2. <kbd>Q</kbd> [mapped to <kbd><esc></kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>!</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>](https://github.com/jalanb/dotjab/blob/master/vim/vimrc#L202)

which means

1. quit, unless something needs to be saved
2. just quit

My meanings for these keys clashes with vim's idea that `stdin` needs to be saved, e.g.

1. `$ git log | vim -`
2. <kbd>q</kbd>
3. vim says `No write since last change ...`
4. Look at keyboard, find <kbd>shift</kbd>
5. <kbd>Q</kbd>

And I can then quit.

How can I tell vim to ignore file saving when using "-" to read for input from stdin?

Comment: Warning about `vim -`: anything sent to stderr is interpreted by vim as a command. To avoid this, you'd want to redirect stderr to stdout: `git log 2>&1 | vim -`

Comment: `q` is very handy and used to record macros (see `:h q`). You may want to think about a different set of keys for you mapping. Maybe use a `<leader>`. See `:h mapleader`.

Comment: I prefer keyboard macros to recordings, and I also use `q` mapped to `exit` in bash, `sys.exit()` in python, and so weiter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would start vim with a command that tells it the current file is a scratch buffer (which vim will not prompt you to save):

```
git log | vim -c "setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=hide noswapfile" -
```

Because I do this a lot, I save the scratch buffer settings to a command in my .vimrc

```
":ScratchBuffer makes current buffer disposable
command! ScratchBuffer setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=hide noswapfile
```

I also add a bash function in my .bashrc

```
v() {
    vim -c ScratchBuffer -
}
```

This means I can type `git log | v` to achieve the desired effect

Comment: Vim also has the `StdinReadPre` and `StdinReadPost` autocmds, which could be used to do this for you automatically. You could also use the `VimEnter` autocmd, but then you can't distinguish between reading from stdin and just typing `vim` with no arguments ([my answer here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/715/51) actually does something very similar).

Comment: [WFM](https://github.com/jalanb/dotjab/commit/21581c4b57bc6d3c726a1b3011c24bb423712d85), YMMV

Comment: Thanks @Carpetsmoker
https://gitlab.com/phunehehe/my-env/blob/6fba38e4af8cdae3938c6b1c4592186ecbbffcdd/vim/vimrc#L92-93

Answer (score 7):

You can run vim in read-only mode (as you're not opening a proper file):

```
git log | vim -R -
```

Then standard <kbd>q</kbd> should work, without asking you to save your changes.