# Windows: disable Vim's start or intro screen

Tags: microsoft-windows

The same as the [existing question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/627/how-can-i-change-vims-start-or-intro-screen), but for the [Windows console version](https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer).

I do not see "startify.vim".

Comment: Hi and welcome! Would you please like to tell us what you are trying to achieve, what you've tried so far and what does not work? Even with the link, it's not that obvious, in this post the OP does *not* want *startify*. Do you?

Comment: Please [edit] to provide details and create a standalone question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the following line to your vimrc

```
set shm+=I
```

See docs at `:h 'shm'`.

Answer (score 0):

For `gVimPortable` I had to add a `gVimPortable.ini` file to the same directory as my `gVimPortable.exe`

```
[GVimPortable]
GVimDirectory=App\vim\vim72
SettingsDirectory=Data\settings
SettingsFile=vimrc
GVimExecutable=gvim.exe
AdditionalParameters=
DisableSplashScreen=true
```