# How to display ASCII art in Neovim startup screen without plugin?

Tags: neovim, startup, ascii, init.vim, ascii-art

Here's the ASCII art image I want to display in nvim dashboard:

```
  "                                   ",
  "   ⣴⣶⣤⡤⠦⣤⣀⣤⠆     ⣈⣭⣿⣶⣿⣦⣼⣆          ",
  "    ⠉⠻⢿⣿⠿⣿⣿⣶⣦⠤⠄⡠⢾⣿⣿⡿⠋⠉⠉⠻⣿⣿⡛⣦       ",
  "          ⠈⢿⣿⣟⠦ ⣾⣿⣿⣷    ⠻⠿⢿⣿⣧⣄     ",
  "           ⣸⣿⣿⢧ ⢻⠻⣿⣿⣷⣄⣀⠄⠢⣀⡀⠈⠙⠿⠄    ",
  "          ⢠⣿⣿⣿⠈    ⣻⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣛⣳⣤⣀⣀   ",
  "   ⢠⣧⣶⣥⡤⢄ ⣸⣿⣿⠘  ⢀⣴⣿⣿⡿⠛⣿⣿⣧⠈⢿⠿⠟⠛⠻⠿⠄  ",
  "  ⣰⣿⣿⠛⠻⣿⣿⡦⢹⣿⣷   ⢊⣿⣿⡏  ⢸⣿⣿⡇ ⢀⣠⣄⣾⠄   ",
  " ⣠⣿⠿⠛ ⢀⣿⣿⣷⠘⢿⣿⣦⡀ ⢸⢿⣿⣿⣄ ⣸⣿⣿⡇⣪⣿⡿⠿⣿⣷⡄  ",
  " ⠙⠃   ⣼⣿⡟  ⠈⠻⣿⣿⣦⣌⡇⠻⣿⣿⣷⣿⣿⣿ ⣿⣿⡇ ⠛⠻⢷⣄ ",
  "      ⢻⣿⣿⣄   ⠈⠻⣿⣿⣿⣷⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡟ ⠫⢿⣿⡆     ",
  "       ⠻⣿⣿⣿⣿⣶⣶⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡟⢀⣀⣤⣾⡿⠃     ",
```

Comment: I suppose by dashboard you mean at startup with no additional functionality. Do I have the correct understanding?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Comment: Maybe could you be interested by the following [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/628/23502)?

Comment: I don't have the faintest idea what the code is referring to. Don't know where to add this ascii text.