# Change what Vim does by default when no files are given

Tags: vimrc, multiple-files, startup

When running `vim` with no command line arguments, it opens a splash screen describing Vim.

I would like to control what `vim` does "by default", so I can make it do something more useful like opening the current directory inside `netrw`, running `:browse old` so I can grab a recently visited file, or running `:grep`  and waiting for me to do a search.

Is there a way to control what Vim does "by default" when it is not given any files to open?

Comment: May be would you be interested to this [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/627/23502)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change Vim's start or intro screen?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/627/how-can-i-change-vims-start-or-intro-screen)

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise may be could uou accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I still don't know how to get `browse oldfiles` to run by default (I think the oldfiles list is populated after your vimrc runs), but that probably belongs in another question. Your answer is very good though and I've accepted it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) Feel free to ask another question about `browse old` we will have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the test used by Startify:

```
fun! Start()
    " Don't run if: we have commandline arguments, we don't have an empty
    " buffer, if we've not invoked as vim or gvim, or if we'e start in insert mode
    if argc() || line2byte('$') != -1 || v:progname !~? '^[-gmnq]\=vim\=x\=\%[\.exe]$' || &insertmode
        return
    endif

    " Do the action you want  
endfun

" Run after "doing all the startup stuff"
autocmd VimEnter * call Start()
```

Extracted from this [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/715/23502)

Comment: The test is subtle, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `~/.vimrc` that opens up the current directory when no files are given as arguments.

```
if argc() ==# 0
  silent execute 'edit .'
endif
```

`vim` has two functions `argv` and `argc` which mimic the behavior of the parameters conventionally called `argv` and `argc` in C, except both are functions.

`argc` returns the number of positional parameters in the argument list.

`vim` will helpfully remove all the command line arguments, so with the above `~/.vimrc`, for example, `vim -y` will still open the current working directory.

---

The other example that I gave earlier today, `browse oldfiles` is more complex.

```
if argc() ==# 0
  silent execute 'browse oldfiles'
endif
```

The above `.vimrc` opens an empty list.

If we remove the `silent`, giving us

```
if argc() ==# 0
  execute 'edit .'
endif
```

then we see the following error message.

```
No old files.
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

This makes me think that my `~/.vimrc` is executing too early, before the oldfiles are actually parsed.

I don't have any idea how to *delay* the evaluation of my `~/.vimrc` though.